# angular-cli custom schematics / collection

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-schematics

I'm trying to create custom schematics for angular cli. So far I have figured out that "collection" has to be compiled, cli cannot read typescript. Which means you can not just clone **https://github.com/angular/devkit/tree/master/packages/schematics/angular** change whatever you need and publish it on npm, which means <s>you need to clone the whole **https://github.com/angular/devkit** and use its `npm run build` to create compiled schematics</s> you need to [run it thru tsc](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7744#issuecomment-332326358), you can then publish those compiled files to npm and globally install with npm, for example

`npm i -g @thescrollbar/schematics`

then I should have been able to do `ng new --collection=@thescrollbar/schematics my-app` but surprisingly enough, it did not work and was throwing `tree.branch is not a function`.

But if you copy this globally installed package to cli's module

`/usr/local/bin/node_modules/@thescrollbar/schematics` -> `/usr/local/bin/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@thescrollbar/schematics`

it starts working and you can create a new app that is based on your schematics..

Now for the new problem I have no workaround for, when I try to generate a new components with

`ng g c --collection=@thescrollbar/schematics logo`

it creates it using `@schematics/angular` template, instead of my collection, despite the fact that when I on purpose do

`ng g shat --collection=@thescrollbar/schematics logo`

it says

> Schematic "shat" not found in collection "@thescrollbar/schematics".

which I think clearly indicates that it indeed is using my collection?

Anyone managed to get custom collections working? Globally and for generating components / modules?

Comment: I added some snippets and information to https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7744 from what I've been able to get working so far.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> /usr/local/bin/node_modules/@thescrollbar/schematics -> /usr/local/bin/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@thescrollbar/schematics

Yes, this is a problem with the current implementation. That's because we (blindly) call `require.resolve` on the collection name, which only resolves from the current module which is the CLI. There is a fix incoming ([PR 163](https://github.com/angular/devkit/pull/163)) that should be released this week that will resolve using the following list:

- is it a node package relative to process.cwd()?
- is it a node package relative to the tool (CLI in your case)?
- is it a node package installed globally?

You might notice there is two missing fallbacks that's missing; is it a package relative to your schematics and is it a package relative to your project? That's coming, it's just a bit more complicated to implement. In any case, you could install your schematic globally and that will work fine.

> ng g c --collection=@thescrollbar/schematics logo
>
> it creates it using @schematics/angular template, instead of my collection

That's a known problem and we have a PR that fixes it in the CLI. This is a fix that's also coming.

Thanks for trying out Schematics. It's been a long time project now and we're still fixing a lot of the little edge cases. We're also going to have better documentation and tutorials (including a schematics schematic) very soon. It's pretty much a work in progress, so thank you for being so patient with it.

You can file issues and bugs in the Angular DevKit repo (https://github.com/angular/devkit).

Comment: GREAT answer! (by the developer who wrote schematics)

Comment: Is it all fixed by now?

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix for cli 1.4.1 is to edit node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/new.js, in the run:function(commandOptions, rawArgs) change the line

`commandOptions.collectionName = this.getCollectionName(rawArgs);`

to

`commandOptions.collectionName = commandOptions.collection || this.getCollectionName(rawArgs);`